# Jump to a state not defined on the jbpm pageflow

Tags: seam, jbpm, page-flow

I have a pageflow with 4 steps,

```
<pageflow-definition name="test" xmlns="http://jboss.com/products/seam/pageflow" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 

 <start-page name="create" view-id="/create.xhtml" back="enabled" no-comversation-view-id="home.xhtml">
  <redirect />
  <transition name="next" to="confirmation" />
  <transition name="cancel" to="end" />
 </start-page>

 <page name="confirmation" view-id="/confirm.xhtml" back="enabled">
  <redirect />
  <transition name="next" to="review"/>
  <transition name="prev" to="create" />
  <transition name="cancel" to="end" />
 </page>

 <page name="review" view-id="/review.xhtml" >
  <redirect />
  <transition name="finish" to="end" />
 </page>

 <page name="end" view-id="/home.xhtml">
  <redirect/>
  <end-conversation before-redirect="true"/>
 </page>

</pageflow-definition>
```

And I want to add a rule/state in the page flow so that if I return a navigation that is not defined in the page flow, it will go to a failsafe state.

The goal of this is to be able to define a template with some predefined links, and be able to jump to any of the links defined in the template without breaking the page flow.

Is this possible?

Thanks, I appreciate any  help.